# UIButton not properly sizing for currentTitle

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I am using NSLocalizableStringFromTable to set the text of various components of my user interface.  I have run into a problem with UIButtons when the text is longer than the placeholder text in the Interface builder.  Here is an example comparing the "save" button in English and Spanish:

[image: Save/Guardar]

When I check the value of _theSaveButton using NSLog I get

_theSaveButton.**titleLabel** = "Save"
_theSaveButton.**currentTitle** = "Guardar"

I have tried using [_theSaveButton sizeToFit], but this seems to always size to the **titleLabel** rather than the **currentTitle**.

Here's a quick code snippet:

```
[_theSaveButton setAttributedTitle:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_theSaveButton setTitle:NSLocalizedStringFromTable(@"Save", applicationLanguage,nil) forState: UIControlStateNormal];

NSLog(@"%@",_theSaveButton.currentTitle);
NSLog(@"%@",_theSaveButton.titleLabel);

[_theSaveButton sizeToFit];
```

FIRST LINE: I've included the setAttributedTitle:nil element here because I read in other places that this solved others' problems, but it is only here for entertainment as far as I can tell.

SECOND LINE: The setTitle method seems to properly set the **currentTitle** and the text changes on the UI as shown above.

So, in the end, I just want the button to resize to handle the localized titles.

Other notes:
- I am using AutoLayout.  I have tried setting a width constraint.  For the moment, I only have constraints on the trailing edge and vertical. Nothing that should constrain the width.
- I tried changing the text to something really long in the interface builder, but that had no impact.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a pinned width constraint. Remember that if you set only 2 constraints, trailing and vertical, missing constraints will be added.

> If you build and run without adding any constraints to an element,
>   you’ll find that Interface Builder fixes the element’s width and
>   height, and pins its position relative to the top left corner of the
>   superview; this means that resizing the window doesn’t move or resize
>   the elements. To make your interface react correctly to changes in
>   size or orientation, you need to start adding constraints. - [Auto Layout Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithConstraints/WorkingwithConstraints.html)

To fix it specify all constants. Basically you need a leading constant with a relation ship equal to or less. Then, the width should be adjusted automatically based on content.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  That was my first guess.  But I've tried every variant from complete constraint definition of everything under the sun to no constraints.  I tried again, using your suggestion, and unfortunately, I get the same result as before.  I think that part of what is happening is the text size calculations are coming from UIButton.textLabel.text rather than UIButton.currentTitle.  But that's a guess.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this won't be the answer in every case, but here's what finally worked:

I went to the location in Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/... and cleared out all of the products of various builds.  Then ran the app again.  Voilá... and I don't even speak French, but it seems to have fixed all of the conundrums.  Even Clean and an Xcode restart didn't fix this problem, but this clean-out did the trick.

I'm guessing that when Xcode doesn't make sense, try this [Xcode knockSomeSenseIntoMe:(DoItWithFinder *) cleanEverythingOutByHand];

It took an airplane flight to sort it out.  Maybe that's part of the solution too!